# Why are some YouTube videos uploaded to a WebView using the IFrame Player API and others cannot?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I have two video

1 - [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGH4EJsPQrI)

2 - [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leysYtupB9E)

When I include and add them to my Android app using WebView and IFrame Player API:

The first video works fine without problems.

While the second video does not play and gives me the error message: Video unavailable.

As the pictures show:

The first video: [image]

The second video: [image]

Is there a solution to the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: some youtube video when it upload, it mark as can't embedding]

Some youtube video when it upload, it mark as can't embedding

Comment: thank you bro
This video is not from my channel
So I have to ask the channel owner to make the video embeddable